# Is there a way to run Azure Storage Emulator on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, sdk, azure

I'm trying to set up my development environment, and I need to use Azure Storage Emulator for my project. Currently I'm running the emu on a VM and my software connects to it.
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I've never work with it, but it sounds as something Microsoft's, and as you asked here, I guess it's not released for GNU/Linux, right? Then I think you have just two options: either a virtual machine, or WINE.

Comment: There's no Azure Storage Emulator for Linux. It comes with the Azure SDK. WINE doesn't work, because the SDK is asking for SQL Server 2012 LocalDB or later when I'm trying to install the SDK from the official MSI installer.

Comment: Did you try to install "SQL Server 2012 LocalDB or later" with WINE? Apps would connect to it through a socket, so as long as it works, it's fine. Just, make sure you have the latest WINE as it's a constantly evolving software, and in every minor release there're a bunch of changes and fixes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Azure Storage emulator for Linux and there will be none according to Microsoft response on [this customer feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/7048446-provide-storage-emulation-for-mac-and-linux).

They advise, however, using open-source alternative like [Azurite](https://github.com/arafato/azurite).

Comment: +1 For Azurite, it's working great! Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

### Update 2022

Azurite has replaced the Azure Storage Emulator. See the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio-code).

Azurite works, among others, on Ubuntu. From their [official repository](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite): "Based on **Node.js**, Azurite provides **cross platform experiences** for customers wanting to try Azure Storage easily in a local environment."

Answer (score 0):

## Update 2023

For me best way is to use docker:

```
docker run -p 10000:10000 -p 10001:10001 -p 10002:10002 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
```